# Displaying an Informative Message in the Face of an Invalid Login

Tags: asp.net, security, authentication

I have a Login control login1. When an user login his username and password, I want to display error message if something wrong.
By this [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20211016204853/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/050306-1.aspx#postadlink), we can easily fire an event by Login1_LoginError. However for some reason, our code always use Login1_Authenticate.
Sample code:

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e) 
{ 
        bool UserAuthenticated = false; 
        MembershipProvider AuthenticationProviderUsed = null; 
        RoleProvider roleProvider = Roles.Providers["SqlRoleProvider"]; 
        MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(login1.UserName); 
        if (user != null && user.IsLockedOut) 
        { 
         \\ display error message
        }
```

My question is can I use the code inside the Login1_Authenticate enent? Because it used to be inside Login1_LoginError event.

Thanks.

```
Login1.FailureText = "Your account has been locked out blah blah.....";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Login.Authenticate Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.authenticate.aspx) will be fired off every time there is an attempt to authenticate; it is where you can provide custom authentication.  In this event, you should perform authentication and set `e.Authenticated` to `true` or `false`.  Likely, if you set it to `false`, you'll get to your `Login1_LoginError` handler.  However, you can handle the failure to authenticate properly in the `Login1_Authenticate` handler without issue - you do not have to use `Login1_LoginError`.

Answer (score 0):

That's the good one, I tried as well
http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/controls/howto-errors-login-asp4-csharp/